# Getting "table name X specified more than once" when attempting this seemingly valid Sequelize query with Postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

At wits-end with this one. I cannot change the model at this point - at least not anything that'd change the database itself.

I've got the following table associations:

```
profile_organization.hasMany(profile, { foreignKey: "organization_id" });
profile.belongsTo(profile_organization, { as: "ProfileOrganization", foreignKey: "organization_id" });

profile_user.hasMany(profile, { foreignKey: "user_account_id" });
profile.belongsTo(profile_user, { as: "ProfileUser", foreignKey: "user_account_id" });

profile_user.belongsToMany(profile_organization, { 
    as: "ProfileOrganizations", 
    through: user_to_organization, 
    foreignKey: "user_id" 
});
profile_organization.belongsToMany(profile_user, { 
    as: "ProfileUsers", 
    through: user_to_organization, 
    foreignKey: "organization_id" 
});
```

This query works:

```
let data = await profile_user.findOne({
    where: {
        auth_user_account_id: user.id,
        active: true
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: profile_organization,
            as: "ProfileOrganizations",
            required: false,
            include: [
                {
                    model: profile,
                    required: false,
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: profile_organization,
                            as: "ProfileOrganization",
                            required: false,
                            where: { active: true }
                            // include: [
                            //     {
                            //         model: profile_user,
                            //         as: "OrgProfileUsers",
                            //         required: false
                            //     }
                            // ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, { raw: true });
```

...but I need it to also grab the commented-out associated users, like so:

```
let data = await profile_user.findOne({
    where: {
        auth_user_account_id: user.id,
        active: true
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: profile_organization,
            as: "ProfileOrganizations",
            required: false,
            include: [
                {
                    model: profile,
                    required: false,
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: profile_organization,
                            as: "ProfileOrganization",
                            required: false,
                            where: { active: true },
                            include: [
                                {
                                    model: profile_user,
                                    as: "ProfileUsers",
                                    required: false
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, { raw: true });
```

I've done weirder queries with Sequelize, this deep in the hierarchy, so I feel like it must be the associations in the model?

I always end up with:

> table name
> "ProfileOrganizations->profiles->ProfileOrganization->ProfileUse"
> specified more than once

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you faced the PostgreSQL limitation for identifiers - 64 characters max. To solve the issue you need to indicate `minifyAliases: true` in Sequelize instance options, see [Sequelize instance constructor](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#instance-constructor-constructor)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. It didn't change the error, however. It doesn't appear to have affected the generated query, either...at least not that I can tell.

Comment: Please show how you indicated the option and also please indicate the version of Sequelize

Comment: I'd love to, but for hours all I get is "too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later." I'm using sequelize 6.6.2 and I added the flag on the Sequelize() params, per the documentation. Seems to be no difference in the result or behavior.

Comment: Did you get the exact same error or slightly different one? Can you compare generated SQL queries?

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what I missed on the first attempt, but I do see aliases like "ProfileOrganizations"."id" AS "_0" now, which is great. It got rid of a separate issue, where field names were trunacating. Thanks so much for the heads up! However, the "table name specified more than once" doesn't go away, unfortunately.

Comment: Try to use special methods to load lazily `ProfileUsers` instead of including them in the query. You have too many nested `include` options. It could dramatically decrease the query performance and increase memory consumption.